# JavaScript append value to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There are quite a few similar questions but I couldn't get their answers to work.

```
 let obj = {};

 const key;//a string
 const value;//a string

 obj[key].push(value);
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I don't know how to do this. I want it to add a new key and value if it doesn't exist, but if it *does* exist it should append it to the end of the values for that particular key. ie like the normal push action with arrays.

Expected behaviour:

```
key = 'hello'
value = 'thanks'

obj = {'hello' : ['thanks']}

key = 'goodbye'
value = 'ok'

obj = {'hello' : ['thanks'], 'goodbye' : ['ok']}

key = 'hello'
value = 'why'

obj = {'hello' : ['thanks','why'], 'goodbye' : ['ok']}
```

The value 'why' is appended to the end for key 'hello'.

EDIT: All values are put into arrays.

Comment: Why do you do `obj = {'hello' : 'thanks'}` and not `obj = {'hello' : ['thanks']}` if you know in advance that `hello` is going to hold more than one value?

Comment: @lealceldeiro That's not what I'm doing, that's the expected output, so if it would put it in an array like that then that's fine.

Comment: Is the value guaranteed to be a string? If the first value is an array, there would be no way to figure out during the second add whether the original value is the array or it has already been converted into an array.

Comment: @ShioT Yes the values and keys will always be strings.

Comment: Case in point: `obj.add('key', [1, 2])` and `obj.add('key', 1); obj.add('key', 2)` produces the same object, but they must be treated differently when you try to add one more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple - use the logical OR operator `||`:

```js
let obj = {};

const key = "key";
const value = "value";

obj[key] = obj[key] || [];
obj[key].push(value);
obj[key].push("anotherValue");

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: What if you start with `{key: "value"}` instead of an empty object?

Comment: This creates `{
  "key": [
    "value"
  ]
}` which is not what OP wants. Only if the property is assigned again, it should create an array

Comment: @adiga - no - read [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455498/javascript-append-value-to-object/56455548#comment99503359_56455498) below question

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski only if you choose to interpret it that way [which seems wrong, as OP *expects* strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455498/javascript-append-value-to-object#comment99503471_56455498)

Comment: @VLAZ - these two points of view are mutually exclusive - first says that only strings allowed, second that arrays allowed

Comment: @VLAZ btw: in your profile you have code `theQuestion = 2b || !2b` - but in most languages `2b` is illegal statement (eg. variables cant starts by number in js)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski I don't think OP is saying arrays are "allowed" or not. OP was answering a question that suggested starting with `{"key" : ["value"]}` to which the answer as that yes, *then* it would work but I don't think OP was agreeing that he would *start* with an array with a single element. The later comment does lend credence to this. Appears that OP wants to add to various keys that would have string values and turn them into arrays at that point.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski that piece of code was a joke...no need to over-analyse its correctness. ["*To be, or not to be, that is the question*"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56965/speech-to-be-or-not-to-be-that-is-the-question)

Comment: I don't see a problem with all the values being in an array, even if there is only one value...which there often will be in my case.

Answer (score 6):

You could create custom function for this that checks if the key exists in object and based on that sets value directly or turns it into an array.

```js
let obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

let add = (obj, key, val) => {
  if (key in obj) obj[key] = [].concat(obj[key], val);
  else obj[key] = val;
}

add(obj, 'foo', 'baz');
add(obj, 'bar', 'baz');

console.log(obj)
```

You could also use `Proxy` with `set` trap that will run when you try to set new property on proxy object.

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    if (prop in obj) obj[prop] = [].concat(obj[prop], value)
    else obj[prop] = value;
  }
})

proxy.foo = 'bar';
proxy.bar = 'baz';
console.log(proxy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this via [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in a pretty concise way:

```js
let o = {}

let add = (obj, k, v) => Object.assign(obj, obj[k] 
  ? { [k]: [].concat(obj[k], v) } 
  : { [k]: v })

console.log(add(o, 'a', 1))
console.log(add(o, 'b', 2))
console.log(add(o, 'a', 3))
console.log(add(o, 'a', 4))
```

The idea is to use the ternary operator and check if we already have the key and if so concat it to a new array. otherwise just assign a new object.

Answer (score -1):

Try (I take [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455498/javascript-append-value-to-object/56455548#comment99503359_56455498) into account)

```js
let obj = {};

const key = 'some_key';//a string
const value = 'first value' ;//a string


obj[key]= (obj[key]||[]).concat(value);
obj[key]= (obj[key]||[]).concat('next value');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a prototype function for your requirement

```js
Object.prototype.add = function(key, value) {
  if( this[key] != undefined) this[key] = [].concat(this[key], value);
  else this[key] = value;
};

let obj = {'hello' : 'thanks', 'goodbye' : 'ok'}

let key = 'hello'
let value = 'why'
//obj[key] = value;
obj.add(key,value);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: *Why* would you need a prototype function for all objects? At best you can create an object with the `add` functionality and then do `Object.create(adder)` to derive your new ones.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. However, this will also put the first value in an array, but that's quite a standard behaviour if you know it's going to be an array of values.

```
  if(obj[key]){
    obj[key].push(value);
  }
  else{
    obj[key] = [value];
  }
```

Comment: By default, it should just add `value`, not `[value]`

Comment: @adiga - no - read [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455498/javascript-append-value-to-object/56455548#comment99503359_56455498) below question